# Call someURL.xml and start aspx method

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need to call someURL.xml and response should be automaticly generated xml by aspx . Problem is that i cant change the calling becouse its done automaticly by device. And i was looking for how to call someURL.xml instead of someURL.aspx and start generating that xml but withou any succes..? Is that even possible ? if you have any advice pls let me know.

Comment: Are you talking about creating a Generic Http Handler which will stream out XML?

Comment: Yeah something like that, i found how to change response to xml.... but my problem is calling. It must be something.xml

Comment: Yes, I got it. I've done that by using URL rewriting. Every call to the SiteMap.xml I'm "redirecting" to SiteMapHandler.ashx. All on the Global.asax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using IIS at least 7, and have an HttpHandler ( `.ashx` and `.ashx.cs` ) which produces your Xml (let's say its full name is `YourNameSpace.YourHandler`)
you can use the following setting in your web.config :

```
  <system.webServer>
    .
    .
    .
    <handlers>
      <remove name="xmlHdlr"/>
      <add  name="xmlHdlr"   verb="GET" path="*.xml" type="YourNameSpace.YourHandler" /> 
    .
    .
```

This way, all GET queries to `.xml` will be processed by your handler. I assume you will then parse the url or request parameters in the handler `ProcessRequest` method to output different xml documents.